# Upper bound for the complex Beta function

Tags: cv.complex-variables, special-functions, gamma-function

The question is almost the same as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3132173/upper-bound-for-the-complex-beta-function).

What is the upper bound for a complex [Beta function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) $\displaystyle B(s,z)=\frac{\Gamma(s) \Gamma(z)}{\Gamma(s+z)}$ with $0<Re(s)<1$ and $0<Re(z)<1$;$\displaystyle Im(s)>10$, $\displaystyle Im(z)>10$?

Comment: Why the choice of 10? I assumed that you wanted an upper bound or asymptotics as a function of Im(s) and Im(z)

Comment: @Yemon Choi values start at ~14. non-trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function

Answer (score 0):

The command of Mathematica

```
NMaximize[{ComplexExpand[Abs[Gamma[s + I*t]*Gamma[a + I*b]/Gamma[s + a + I*(t + b)]]],s > 0 && a > 0}, {s, t, a, b}]
```

outputs "NMaximize::cvdiv: Failed to converge to a solution. The function may be unbounded." and

> `{4.7857*10^8, {s -> 0.32798, t -> 0.720557, a -> 0.,  b -> -2.08956*10^-9}}`

The command of Mathematica

```
s = 1/2; t = a; MaxLimit[ ComplexExpand[Abs[Gamma[s + I*t]*Gamma[a + I*b]/Gamma[s + a + I*(t + b)]]], {t,b} -> {0, 0},Direction -> "FromAbove"]
```

results in $\infty$, confirming it.

Addition. Here is the answer with Mathematica to the modified question (Thanks to Brendan McKay who paid my attention to the edit.)

```
NMaximize[{ComplexExpand[ Abs[Gamma[s + I*t]*Gamma[a + I*b]/
Gamma[s + a + I*(t + b)]]],  s > 0 && a > 0 && s < 1 && a < 1 && 
b > 10 && t > 10}, {s, t, a, b}]
```

> `{1.121, {s -> 3.70155*10^-7, t -> 10., a -> 3.57795*10^-7, b -> 10.}}`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not asking about the limit, but about the absolute value.

Comment: @user363337: The second result means that  $$ \left| \frac{\Gamma (a+b i) \Gamma (s+i t)}{\Gamma (a+(b+t) i+s)}\right|$$ is unbounded on the set $a>0,a<1,s>0,s<1$ . Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: While I don't know if Mathematica is right or wrong, I don't think the results of executing commands like this form a proof.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay: Can you ground your claim? Are you aware of [Four colors theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem)?

Comment: I use computers to prove things all the time. Symbolic algebra systems make plenty of mistakes, especially when the problem does not have a clean deterministic algorithm such as this 4-dimensional optimisation.  Anyway, the OP added lower bounds on the imaginary parts (I think after your answer) that you haven't used.